# How to make and name multiple text files after using the cut command?

Tags: bash, shell, text, command-line, filenames

I have about 50 data text files that I need to remove several columns from.

I have been using the `cut` command to remove and rename them individually but I will have many more of the files and need a way to do it large scale.

Currently I have been using:

```
cut -f1,6,7,8 filename.txt >> filename_Fixed.txt
```

And I am able to remove the columns from all the files using:

```
 cut -f1,6,7,8 *.txt
```

But I'm only able to get all the output in the terminal or I can write it to a single text file.

What I want is to edit several files using cut to remove the required columns:

```
filename1.txt
filename2.txt
filename3.txt
filename4.txt
.
.
```

.

And get the edited output to write to individual files:

```
filename_Fixed1.txt
filename_Fixed2.txt
filename_Fixed3.txt
filename_Fixed4.txt
.
.
```

.

But haven't been able to find a way to write the output to new text files. I'm new to using the command line and not much of a coder, so maybe I don't know what terms to search for? I haven't even been able to find anything doing google searches that has helped me. It seems like it should be simple, but I am struggling.

In desperation, I did try this bit of code, knowing it wouldn't work:

```
cut -f1,6,7,8 *.txt >> ( FILENAME ".fixed" )
```

I found the portion after `">>"` nested in an `awk` command that output multiple files.

I also tried (again knowing it wouldn't work) to wild card the output files but got an ambiguous redirect error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `for`?

```
for f in *.txt ; do
    cut -f 1,6,7,8 "$f" > $(basename "$f" .txt)_fixed.txt
done
```

(N.B. I can't try the `basename` now, you can replace it with `"${f}_fixed"`)

Comment: I did! Like 3 days ago... I totally forgot, but it was a for loop with some embarrassing and very wrong code to try to get the output into distinct files.  This totally worked by the way. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer such a simple question!!!

Comment: @AlexisDodson my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also process it all in `awk` itself which would make the process much more efficient, especially for large numbers of files, for example:

```
awk '
    NF < 8 { 
        print "contains less than 8 fields: ", FILENAME
        next
    }
    {   fn=FILENAME
        idx=match(fn, /[0-9]+.*$/)
        if (idx == 0) {
            print "no numeric suffix for file: ", fn
            next;
        }
        newfn=substr(fn,1,idx-1) "_Fixed" substr(fn,idx)
        print $1,$6,$7,$8 > newfn
    }
' *.txt
```

Which contains two rules (the expressions between `{...}`). The first:

```
    NF < 8 { 
        print "contains less than 8 fields: ", FILENAME
        next
    }
```

simply checks that the file contains at least 8 fields (since you want field 8 as your last field). If the file contains less than 8 fields, it just skips to the `next` file in your list.

The second rule:

```
    {   fn=FILENAME
        idx=match(fn, /[0-9]+.*$/)
        if (idx == 0) {
            print "no numeric suffix for file: ", fn
            next;
        }
        newfn=substr(fn,1,idx-1) "_Fixed" substr(fn,idx)
        print $1,$6,$7,$8 > newfn
    }
```

- `fn=FILENAME` stores the current filename as `fn` to cut down typing,
- `idx=match(fn, /[0-9]+.*$/)` locates the index where the numeric suffix for the filename begins (e.g. were `"3.txt"` starts),
- `if (idx == 0)` then a numeric suffix was not found, warn, and move on to the `next` file,
- `newfn=substr(fn,1,idx-1) "_Fixed" substr(fn,idx)` form the new filename from the non-numeric prefix (e.g. `"filename"`), add `"_Fixed"` with string-concatenation and then add the numeric suffix, and finally
- `print $1,$6,$7,$8 > newfn` print fields (columns) `1,6,7,8` redirecting output to the new filename.

For more information on each of the string-functions used above, see the [GNU awk User's Guide - 9.1.3 String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions)

If I understand what you were attempting, this should be able to handle as many files as you have -- so long as the files have a numeric suffix to place `"_Fixed"` before in the filename and each file has at least 8 fields (columns). You can just copy/middle-mouse-paste the entire command at the command-line to test.

Comment: Maybe bit of an overkill, but I love it, +1 :)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, a bit longer compared to `cut`, but it will run orders of magnitude faster for large numbers of files (which is where `awk` shines). `awk` runs in a single process. With shell & `cut` in a loop with a command-substitution there are 3-subshells spawned per-iteration (1-cut, 2-basename, 3-command-substitution). For 500 files that's 1500 subshells and the runtime difference will be a number of seconds, for 5,000,000 files that's over 1.5B subshells and the runtime difference will be in the hours.

Comment: The subshells spawned are something we easily forget about. Thanks for the reminder.